# Redirect to list view when users search for an event in The Events Calendar (v2)

Tags: php, wordpress, events

Does anyone know of a way to redirect to a particular view (like list or photo) when users search for an event in The Events Calendar? If the event they're searching for is not in the current month, it just displays "there were no results found for 'search term' this month." My client really wants a default month view, but this message is misleading if the event they're looking for is in a later month.

I'm hoping to hook into the search action, but I'm having trouble nailing down exactly what to hook into.

I've tried redirecting based on the URL and query string, but because this version of The Events Calendar loads views dynamically, the REQUEST_URI is not always correct, I get something like "/wp-json/tribe/views/v2/html" instead.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO questions must be about programming, please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.